# How to stop audio that is playing when back button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer imp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cat);
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dog);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imp.start();
        }
    });


    }
}
```

Comment: override `onBackPressed()` method and pass `imp.stop()` method inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    imp.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the activity's onBackPressed(). Something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (imp.isPlaying()) {
        imp.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code to stop Audio file.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
  if (mp != null)
    mp.stop();
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I hope this may help you.